# GWT text with different colors

Tags: gwt

I had a label that receives a text, example 12 Status 3
I need to put the numbers with a different color.
What is the best way to manage that?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a single label.  You have to use three separate labels, and color each one independently.  You probably want to use `InlineLabel` to keep them all on the same line - I think `InlineLabel` works just like a `<span>` tag.

The best way to color a label is with css or CssResource.

Answer (score 2):

Every piece of text that you want to be a different color will need its own <Span> tag. This is how StackOverflow and other sites have formatted text inline. You could still use a single <Label> element though, and insert a series of  tags.

For example:

```
/* CSS */
label { color:black; }
.red { color:red; }
.blue { color:blue; }
```

GWT:

```
myLabel.setInnerHTML("<span class='red'>12</span> Status <span class='blue'>3</span>");
```

Comment: That's a good point. Use a SafeHtmlTemplate for convenience and to prevent injection attacks~

Comment: One would normally use myLabel.setInnerText() for injection prevention, but if you're certain of your inputs (i.e. two ints) then SafeHtmlTemplates are unnecessary.